# ErrorException Undefined variable $categories

Tags: php, laravel-8

Já tentei fazer vários tipos de tratamento pra resolver esse erro, mas não consigo fazer com que a variável seja reconhecida.

Rotas

```
Route::get('produtos', [CategoryController::class, 'index'])->name('site.products');
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
    ];
    protected $table = 'category';
}
```

CategoryController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Site;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('site.category.index');
        
    }
  

    
    public function show($slug)
    {
        return view(('site.category.show'), compact('slug'));
    }

  
}
```

Category Index

```
@extends('layouts.site')

@section('content')
    <header class="common-header">
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <h1 class="title-large">With apples drink teriyaki. </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="pattern__header"></div>
    </header>
    <!-- Products list -->
    <div class="gray-background">
        <section class="products__cultivation__category main-wrapper">
            @foreach($categories as $category)
            
                <article class="card__product">
                    <a href="{{route('site.products.category', ['category' => $category])}}">
                        <div class="card__cover">
                            <img src="{{asset($category->image)}}">
                        </div>
                        <header class="card__product-header">
                            <h2 class="title-medium">{{$categories->name}}</h2>
                            <p>{{$categories->description}}</p>
                        </header>
                    </a>
                </article>
            @endforeach
        </section>
    </div>
@endsection
```

To preso nesse processo e já não sei mais o que fazer. Tentei criar model, table no MySQL, fiz alterações nos códigos, mas sempre retorna que a variável ou é nula ou não existe. O que eu to fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa retornar a variável $categories para a view

```
   public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('site.category.index',["categories"=>$categories]);
        
    }
```

Comment: Puts amg era isso mesmo, obg de vdd